# Cloth simulation appears corrupt in render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, cloth-simulation

I am having problem with a cycles render.  My cloth simulation for a flag bakes just fine and seems to work.  When I render the image gets fractured (it looks like broken glass instead of cloth).  See attached images.

Someone said to post the blender file.  I can't figure out how to do that.
OK, here is the link to the file:
http://www.pasteall.org/blend/31495

I can't figure out which setting to change in the render settings to get rid of the "z fighting"

[image: this is the first rendered image]

[image: this is the second and all subsequent images are broken in this fashion]

Comment: Post your .blend file. And that looks like z-fighting.

Comment: I think you might be using the wrong simulation... double check all your settings.

Comment: Do you have a modifier which different settings in the render than what you baked with? To me it looks like an invalid cloth cache (causing Z-fighting).

Comment: Upload it to a hosting service like [pasteall](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/), then put the link here

Comment: OK, uploaded:  http://www.pasteall.org/blend/31495

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because the cloth simulation is baked using the *viewport* settings of the modifier(s) above it.
As the subserf modifier above it has a viewport subdivision level of 1, but a render subdivision level of 2, the vertex locations stored in the cache are nonsensical when rendering.

To fix this, just set the render subserf value to 1:

[image]

If you still want to use two subserf levels, you have two options:

- Re-bake, with the viewport subdivisions set to 2
- Add another subserf modifier *below* the cloth modifier. These subdivisions won't be taken into account with the simulation, but they will smooth the result out a little bit (though a smooth modifier could probably get you comparable results with a lot less vertices), and you won't have to rebake.

  [image]